# How do you return a Future based off a Stream you don't control in Dart?

Tags: dart, dart-async

I have a situation where I'm expecting a single value from a `Stream`, but because it's one provided by the browser I can't rely on simply calling `streamSub.single`. Currently, I'm creating an explicit `StreamController` so that I can easily generate a `Future` from it while guaranteeing that it will only get a single response. However, that ends up being a lot more overhead than I was expecting to have to set up, making me think I'm missing something. The current code follows:

```dart
StreamController<String> streamCtrlr = new StreamController<String>();
var popup = window.open(targetUrl, "Auth Window"); 
//The popup above will call window.opener.postMessage, so listen for messages
StreamSubscription sub = window.onMessage.listen(null);
sub.onData((Event){
  /* Logic goes here */
  sub.cancel();
  popup.close();
  streamCtrlr.add(Event.data);
  streamCtrlr.close();
});  
return streamCtrlr.stream.single;
```

How can this be re-written so that the intermediary `StreamController` isn't required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why can't  you rely on calling `streamSub.single`? Is it because there might be more than one message?

Your example code picks the first event in all cases, so to get the same behavior, you can use `window.onMessage.first` instead of `window.onMessage.single`. 
It will still cause an error if there is no first event (but I don't think that can happen with DOM event handlers - they never send a done event), and otherwise it will give a future that is completed with the first event.

You also want to extract the event data, so you will probably want:

```dart
return window.onMessage.first.then((event) {
  /* Logic goes here */
  popup.close();
  return event.data;
});
```

Comment: Yes, I'm wary of using sub.single because there may be multiple messages coming down the pipe. I actually tried that first, but it didn't trigger onData for the first postMessage call, and the second threw an error. I'll try stream.first.

When using stream.first, does it return a future with the first event _since the subscription_ or does it return the first event since the stream was created (meaning since the DOM loaded in this case)?

Comment: Following @lrn's advice, I opted to use `firstWhere` and use the boolean closure to check the origin of the message to ensure it came from the domain I was expecting. Works perfectly! =D

Comment: I believe the DOM streams act as broadcast streams, so they should not buffer events from prior to you listening.